# A question about supernova (explosion decay curve)

Tags: optics, visible-light, cosmology

In the third paragraph of this article: http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/tiredlit.htm
It talks about supernova decay and how a 20 day decay would appear to be a 40 day decay at a distance that has been red shifted. I am not interested in the tired light theory but every time I search supernova light curves it only talks about brightness and not the 20 or 40 day decay sequence. Specifically I am looking for a chart or slope that shows the relation between distance and length of decay.

Edit (The one chart in the article is not clear or I don’t understand it.)
Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't a 20 day curve appear to be a 40 day curve if light was red shifted by a factor of 2? So use the same curve as red shift vs distance.

Comment: @mmesser314 I don’t know if the information on that chart was correct or not. I would like to see the actual information compared to the light curves at different distances.

Answer (score 2):

If you see something at redhshift $z$ it is not just wavelengths that get multiplied $$\lambda_{seen}=(1+z) \lambda_{emitted}$$ but also the time-course of events. To see it, just consider that they happens $x$ wave peaks apart at emission and receiving: $$\Delta t_{seen} = x \lambda_{seen}=x (1+z) \lambda_{emitted} = (1+z) \Delta t_{emitted}.$$ Or, $$\frac{\Delta t_{seen}}{\Delta t_{emitted}}=1+z.$$

Since $z+1=a(t_{now})/a(t_{emitted})=1/a(t_{emitted})$ for the scale factor of the universe, this also allows us to estimate the apparent slowdown for very old processes. However, since $a(t)$ has varied in a nonlinear fashion calculating the distance from the slowdown is trickier, since the distance from "here" to our past light-cone of the present moment at a given $t$ [changes in a messy way](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808). Here you just need to run a cosmological model to get values of $a(t)$ and then interpolate (or, use them to calculate conformal time and co-moving coordinates that make the estimation easier).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will consider it as I learn more. Is there an easy chart or list of time dilations based on mega parsecs or some  consistent measure that I can compare calculation with? Thanks

Comment: @Bill I feel your pain, but as Anders said it's nonlinear and depends on which cosmological model you're using, so you'd need a conversion chart for each model. And that's a major reason why many papers dealing with distant events don't even bother trying to give distances, thet just give z values, since we can easily determine z by observation.

Comment: @PM2Ring OK thanks but I think my question could be simpler than that. I want to know if there is an average length of a super nova explosion. Then I want to know if that average length increases per megaparsec. For instance compare the average explosion time here in the Milky Way galaxy to the average explosion time in the Andromeda galaxy which is .89 Mpc. away. And then beyond that. I’m not asking about a particular model, I’m interested in the collected data of all the different explosion lengths at different distances. Thanks again

Comment: @Bill There are many types of supernova, but I assume you're talking about [type Ia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Ia_supernova) which are used as "standard candles" for cosmological distance measurements because they explode when the white dwarf has reached a certain mass from the matter it's accreted fron its companion, so they *should* all explode in a fairly similar way, with similar light curves.

Comment: @Bill (cont) But we can't observe the distance to the supernova directly, we can only see its relative luminosity and spectrum (and hence redshift) and how those change over time. To calculate the actual distance we have to choose a cosmological model in order to convert redshift to distance.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, from what I have read they do explode in a similar time frame. I have read several articles that briefly discuss how these explosions appear to be longer and longer the further away they are. I am just looking for accurate data on that particular information.